# How to echo an array value

Tags: php, arrays

I am fairly new to PHP and I am writing a PHP function that grabs an object from SOAP.
I found a code to convert it to an array but I can't manage to echo any data.

The array from print_r

```
Array
(
    [Status] => Array
        (
            [Code] => 0
            [Message] => OK
        )

    [Order] => Array
        (
            [OrderNumber] => 9334543
            [ExternalOrderNumber] => 
            [OrderTime] => 2014-07-15T15:20:31+02:00
            [PaymentMethod] => invoice
            [PaymentStatus] => Paid
            [ShipmentMethod] => Mypack
            [DeliveryStatus] => Delivered
            [Language] => sv
            [Customer] => Array
                (
                    [CustomerId] => 13556
                    [CustomerNumber] => 
                    [Username] => admin
                    [Approved] => 1
                    [OrgNumber] => 9309138445
                    [Company] => 
                    [VatNumber] => 
                    [FirstName] => Jane
                    [LastName] => Doe
                    [Address] => Gatan
                    [Address2] => 
                    [Zip] => 1230
                    [City] => Staden
                    [Country] => Sweden
                    [CountryCode] => SE
                    [PhoneDay] => 84848474
                    [PhoneNight] => 
                    [PhoneMobile] => 
                    [Email] => mail@msn.com
                    [NewsLetter] => 
                    [OrgType] => person
                    [OtherDelivAddress] => 
                    [DelivName] => 
                    [DelivAddress] => 
                    [DelivAddress2] => 
                    [DelivZip] => 
                    [DelivCity] => 
                    [DelivCountry] => 
                    [DelivCountryCode] => 
                )

            [Comment] => 
            [Notes] => 9063025471 UK/MA
            [CurrencyCode] => SEK
            [ExchangeRate] => 1
            [LanguagePath] => se
            [FreightWithoutVat] => 0
            [FreightWithVat] => 0
            [FreightVatPercentage] => 25
            [PayoptionFeeWithoutVat] => 0
            [PayoptionFeeWithVat] => 0
            [PayoptionFeeVatPercentage] => 25
            [CodWithoutVat] => 0
            [CodWithVat] => 0
            [CodVatPercentage] => 0
            [DiscountWithoutVat] => 0
            [DiscountWithVat] => 0
            [DiscountVat] => 0
            [TotalWithoutVat] => 4388
            [TotalWithVat] => 5485
            [TotalVat] => 1097
            [PayWithoutVat] => 
            [AffiliateCode] => 
            [AffiliateName] => 
            [OrderField] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => external_ref
                            [Value] => 43445
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => webshopid
                            [Value] => 423
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => webshopname
                            [Value] => Manuell
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Non working code

```
echo $array[1][0]
```

I have tried different combos of indexes. I know how to return the values from the soap object but if I could do it this way it would be easier. It should work shouldn't it?

Comment: Which part would you WANT to be echoed?

Comment: Well address, last name etc. but as long as i manage to echo one value i can get rest to work

Comment: as @Mehedi-PSTU said, please post the print_r of this array as the var_dump is very hard to read or navigate.

Comment: @user3848819 it is quite hard to see what is the content of the array as its all in one line. mehed probably meant that if you give use what you get with print_r that it will be easier for us to read and thus help you out.

Comment: I edited my post with the outcome of print_r

Comment: Okay sorry about this but your print_r doesn't follow fancy rules, so please do so again using `var_export($array);`

Comment: Good enough to traverse, check out my answer.

Comment: hah, @Marcin beat me to it

Comment: As a comment to the given answers: "[Order] => Array"  the part before the => is always the key (without the [] ) that you need to use to refer to the data inside the field.

Comment: @user3848819 i have updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$array['Status']['Code']` , `$array['Status']['Message']`, `$array['Order']['OrderNumber']`, `$array['Order']['Customer']['CustomerId']` and so on to display your data. It's an associative array so you need to use string keys and not numbers

Comment: I have provided the same answer 8 minutes before Marcin Nabiałek did. And my answer got down voted 2 times but his got selected as the accepted answer. @user3848819 I'm just curious... Am i missing something? I checked the answers edit logs, but i can't find anything...

Comment: @tastro Probably your answer was too short but I don't know. I didn't downvote you so hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

$array[1] is the second index of the array. the key of this array us "Status", this array contains a code and message

i assume you want to echo the message, you can do that with the following

```
echo $array[1]["Status"]["Message"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the arrays elements with the string keys, not the integer ones you are using:

```
echo $array['Order']['Customer']['Address'];
```

Another way you could see what is going on is by iterating through the array, and print out the keys and values:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  echo "Key=$key value=$value<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$array['Order']['Customer']['LastName']
```

is my best guess without losing my sanity in that one line.
But for us to be sure please post the `print_r($array)` output

Answer (score 0):

There are some way I always do this:

```
print_r($array);
```

And the other way is

```
$array[0]['Order']['LastName']
```